# Is there a way to study formal systems in general?

Tags: formal-languages, formal-proofs, formal-systems

I was reading Gödel Escher Bach, and the author explains that mathematics is just an example of something broader: formal systems. So I wonder wether there exists a theory to study formal systems in general, not just applied to mathematics, formal logic or computation, but a general theory which encompasses all formal systems and when applied to those areas give known results. Some book recommendations would be nice.

Comment: Of course the Wikipedia article gives one attempt to define the concept. Wolfram Mathematica is an attempt to build a software system based on a formal system.

Comment: It's a bit hard to guess what you're looking for, but you might be interested in reading about [formal grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar), which describe what things can be written in a formal system, and topics like [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form). This arguably doesn't encompass *all* formal systems, but the [Metamath language](http://us.metamath.org/#faq) (not to be confused with a body of math written for it like [MPE](http://us.metamath.org/mpeuni/mmset.html)) can process all sorts of substitution rules, like the MIU system.

Comment: See *Theory of Formal Systems* by Raymond Smullyan. These days you're more likely to encounter relevant research in Computer science departments, not maths.

Comment: See e.g. R.Kaye, [The Mathematics of Logic: A Guide to Completeness Theorems and Their Applications](https://books.google.it/books?id=EOjT_j-qOnsC&printsec=frontcover)